# Undefined href! (DOM API)

Tags: javascript, dom

On google's search results page,

```
document.getElementsByClassName("l")[0] 
//"l" is the class for the URL's of the results.
```

Returns undefined.

However,

```
alert(document.getElementsByClassName("l")[0]);
```

Will display the actual URL of the first result.

I just need to access the URL's of the results!

```
      //Adding
.href //to the end does not help
```

You can experience this by going to your browser console and entering

```
document.getElementsByClassName("l")[0]
```

Comment: It works fine for me. Also, why not use their API?

Comment: Who's API? Thought document.* was the DOM API

Comment: He's referring to the Google Search API, which should be easier to use then to screen scrape the search results page

Comment: When are you running the code? In `<head>` or after the DOM has finished loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: it works fine in the search results, I was doing it in the homepage initially.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("l")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want just the `href` attribute:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('l')[0].getAttribute('href');
```

This works fine in Firefox/Firebug, Safari, and Chrome.